# PHP: How do I concatenate a foreach inside a string?

Tags: php, pdf, foreach, concatenation, mpdf

I want to create a PDF generator using MPDF's library. In the table I've created inside the PDF Generator (Using HTML of course), I want to execute a foreach() loop. 
This is my code:

```
$html = '<td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
    // Here I want foreach concatenation
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
    // Here I want foreach concatenation                                
</td>
<td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">
    // Here I want foreach concatenation                                
';
```

I tried using the normal technique with variables. ('.$var.'), but that didn't work out. 
I also tried a anonymous function...

```
            $PDFFunction = 
                function($arr) {
                    foreach($arr as $key) {
                       // And now somewhere, i've got to return the $key... But I tried in the foreach loop and outside the loop...
                    }
                };
```

As you see in my comment, I don't know where I've to place the return() function. 
When I placed it in the loop, it only showed the first key and when i placed it outside the loop (but within the function) i only got the last key...
Does anyone know the solution to this?

With kind regards...

Comment: Is this a question about [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your foreach loop? And what is stored in your $arr array?

Comment: @kenef What i want to do is to insert an array inside the PDF document. (The array is fetched from my database). The array looks like this: ```Array ( [0] => First Array index [1] => 2nd Array index [2] => 3rd Array index )```. The $arr array is the array where the loop is executed in. ```$pdfOmschrijving = $PDFFunction($pdfOmschrijving);```

Comment: @ficuscr No, it's not about variable scope. However, it would be nice to create a variable in the loop and being able to use it outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't completely clear what you "want to concatenate" within the PDF but you may do it directly within the document as it is being built. Included below is a portion of your `$html` variable with the inclusion of `foreach` loops based on your description of what you are trying to do.

```
$html = '</tr>
          <tr>
              <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">';

foreach($arr as $key) {
    $html .= $key;
}

$html .= '</td> 
          <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">';
foreach($arr as $key) {
    $html .= $key;
}
$html .= '</td> 
          <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;">';
foreach($arr as $key) {
    $html .= $key;
}
$html .= '</td>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried it and you code worked!